# How python wait for upload file progress to 100% using playwright wait

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, element, playwright-python

I have a question about playwright, how can playwright "wait" for the upload to complete (%).

I'm using playwright to upload png file redbubble. While uploading, i find out only 1 "class" change from 'single-upload with-uploader uploading-image' to 'single-upload with-uploader has-image'.

This is the picture for better refrence. I hope someone can give solution to this. I already try page.wait_for_... and some elementhandle but nothing work

And this is a html code during and after upload image

this is the image
[image]

During the upload: div class="**single-upload with-uploader uploading-image**" data-work-url="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.:remote_key.0/flat,300x300,075,f.jpg" style="display: flex;"

After finish upload: div class="**single-upload with-uploader has-image**" data-work-url="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.:remote_key.0/flat,300x300,075,f.jpg" style="display: flex;"

Comment: the page is open? We can try? Did you try https://playwright.dev/python/docs/input#upload-files